# How do I delete values in an XY table greater than a tolerance?

Tags: matlab

I have a large table that has some duplicate values that are entered as zero. I would like to delete the duplicate XY pair if Y=0

```
      X     Y
-----------------------
     95.8   0.004064782
(del)95.8   0
     95.9   0
     96.0   0
     96.1   0
     96.2   0
     96.3   0.008730802
(del)96.3   0
     96.4   0
     96.5   0
     96.6   0
     96.7   0
     96.8   0.00531453
(del)96.8   0
```

I have tried utilizing the command *data = unique(data)* but the table still remains the same. How can I delete the duplicate rows where Y(X)=0 or in the more general case if Y(X)

Comment: From your data it looks like whenever you have a duplicate X the Y is zero and that observation trails the valid observation. If that is true you can use `unique` to get the index of unique rows and then get only those rows out of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your data it looks like whenever you have a duplicate X the Y is zero and that observation trails the valid observation. However I am assuming that it may not always hold true. As a first step you can then sort by X and then by Y in descending order such that the non zero value of Y will be the first observation. If your table is named `data`

```
>> data = sortrows(data,[1 -2]); % Sort by 1st column first and 2nd column in descending order 
>> [~, idx] = unique(data.X); % Find all unique values of X, unique returns first index which would be the one which has non zero Y value
>> data = data(idx,:); % Get only the rows with unique Xs
```

You may not need to `sortrows` if `Y = 0` always trails the valid observation. Also, beware that this method will ignore non zero duplicate values of Y, meaning if data has:

X ---- Y
95.8 --- 0.4
95.8 --- 0.6

This method will pick only [95.8 0.6].

Comment: I just tried attempted this using R2014a but the same data table is being produced. For some reason it still will not tease out the unique X~=0 values within this table. 

Is this because I'm treating this set of data as a Table instead of a matrix array?

Comment: I just did it using R2016a and it works as expected. After you sortrows does the Y column look sorted ? Does unique work correctly ?

Comment: When I sort it appears that nothing happens. One thing I noticed as well is that  [~, idx] = unique(data.X) still indexes a duplicate X value as unique so the end result of applying data = data(idx,:); does not work correctly.

I have updated to 2016a and still come about this issue. Im trying to think, is this maybe because the X-values are not treated as numbers?

Comment: I have figured it out- It turns out that my X-values were not of the same decimal point value, thus Matlab treated 95.8 and 95.80 as unique. This was remedied by setting the decimal point value to be uniform throughout the dataset.
Once that was carried out, the unique indexing worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a bash shell
    cat yourFile.txt | sort | unique
will achieve desired results but it will not round the numbers for you deleting numbers that are close in value. For this see and adjust the precision as necessary.
see 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99400/how-can-i-round-all-numbers-in-a-file
for rounding all numbers in a file

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. when you have a link in your answer, it is probable that the page get removed and your answer get useless for other people in the future